# HttpClient Authorization Header start with 'key='

Tags: c#, authorization, httpclient, httpcontent

I have the following code, and I want to set the Authorization of the post request to be like this:

`Authorization:key=somevalue`

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     using (StringContent jsonContent = new StringContent(json))
     {
         jsonContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

         using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", jsonContent))
         {
            var reponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         }
     }
}
```

how to do this? I am really struggling
and the following statement

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);
```

thrown the following exception

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   System.Net.Http.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Do you have first chance exceptions enabled? If so, turn them off.

Comment: I would myself prefer using `FormUrlEncodedContent` for this purpose, to send the keys and other stuff as if I was submitting the form. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved this by the following line of code.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", "=" + apiKey);
```

Comment: Depending on how the HTTP Client is stored this may not be thread safe. The error that will occur is "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: doesn't it add a space between `key` and `=`?

Comment: @TimTimWong I do not know, It just worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still running, but basic auth key and something like a 64 hash authed key would be added to something like a REST call like:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new();
string tokenKey = "<some token key>";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", tokenKey);
```

Comment: This solution worked great. i could even say new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenKey); thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved using :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic jMxMTgwMWUzYWFkYTk4NjM2MjcyOTk3MDowYTU0N2I2NzliNWRkMjliN2I4NTFlMDBkY2Y2NjQzNzQ5OTIxYzZl";
```

where the string after `Basic` is an encoded string from Postman, the option is 'code'.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I do not think this is the same problem, because you are using `HttpWebRequest` and I am using `HttpClient`